# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable after install 'dotnet-hosting-2.2.1-win'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-core

My application was developed on .net framework web forms and asp.net MVC
Application hosted on Windows server 2012 R2 and applications running on IIS server without any failures.

After that, I installed 'dotnet-hosting-2.2.1-win' on the same server because my new application developed on .net core.

Then previously installed web forms and MVC application not running, give the error as 'HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable'. When enter the URL stop the web site on application pool. So please help me for overcome the above hosting issue

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Check if VC++ 2015 runtime is installed.

Comment: VC++ 2015 runtime is not installed. VC++ 2008 and VC++ installed

Comment: Then you have to install it (x86 and/or x64).

Comment: After install VC++ 2015 its work for asp.net web forms only. Asp.Net MVC applications not running still give the error 'HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable'

Comment: After install VC++ 2015 its work for asp.net web forms only. Asp.Net MVC applications not running still give the error 'HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. Any other pre-requested .net packages to install?